# Xamarin Grid Row's Content Overlapping Rows

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to create a simple "Chat" window. The issue I'm running into is the row's content are extending outside the ListView row itself.

It seems the row isn't adjusting it's height.

It works correctly running as a UWP app but not running in iOS.I tested on both an iPad and iPhone - devices and simulators.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestApp.Views"
             x:Class="TestApp.Views.ChatConversation">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="FromTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Margin="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Text="{Binding SentOn}" TextColor="LightGray"/>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="Blue">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Blue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="Start" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="Blue" Text="{Binding Message}" TextColor="White"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="ToTemplate">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Margin="20">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="6*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Text="{Binding SentOn}" TextColor="LightGray"/>
                        <Frame CornerRadius="10" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="LightBlue">
                            <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightBlue" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Label HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" Text="{Binding Message}"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>

            <local:ChatRowTemplateSelector x:Key="ChatRowTemplateSelector"
                                                     FromTemplate="{StaticResource FromTemplate}"
                                                     ToTemplate="{StaticResource ToTemplate}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <Image x:Name="profileImage" HeightRequest="70"></Image>
            <ListView x:Name="conversationListView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ChatRowTemplateSelector}"></ListView>
            <Grid HeightRequest="110" Margin="20">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="9*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Entry x:Name="MessageToSend"></Entry>
                <ImageButton Source="Assets/downarrow02.png"  Grid.Column="1" Clicked="SendButton_Clicked"/>

            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: the first thing I would try is setting `HasUnevenRows` to true

Comment: Do you mean the text will extend outside if the message is too long? Does it occur if without a DataTemplateSelector?

Comment: Here is the doc for list appearance you may refer to [Row Height](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#row-height). Also, you may try using CollectionView which aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to ListView.